# How to remove underline on hover?

Tags: css, hover, underline

I can't remove the underline on hover on this page:

http://www.studyroomguides.net/?page_id=19

I have tried adding:

```
.a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

I'd like the underline to be removed on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because there is no text decoration on hover.Look closely and you will notice that on hover it's border-bottom.Remove that border and you'll be fine.
This is your css on hover:

```
.entry-content a:hover{
border-bottom-color: #424242;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `.` before `a:hover`. The `.` symbol indicates a CSS class, but `a` is an element (a stands for anchor), not a class name. It should be: `a:hover { text-decoration: none; }`.

Comment: maybe the op confused classes and psuedoclasses and ended up mixing them together